# Как отправить эксель таблицу в виде изображения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

У телеграм во всех уже версиях на пк есть функция для отправки фрагмента эксель-таблицы в виде изображения: выделяешь нужные ячейки, копируешь, вставляешь в сообщение, и туда вставляется изображение, идентичное выделенному фрагменту таблицы.

Существует ли способ реализовать такой функционал для телеграм бота, чтобы бот мог скидывать эксель-документ в сразу читаемом формате? Не смог найти упоминаний в официальной документации телеграмовского апи, но вдруг.

У бота уже и так довольно большая кодовая база с использованием telebot, но если этот функционал есть в какой-нибудь другой библиотеке, то можно и переписать, настолько надо. Уж очень не нравится вариант прописывать генерацию изображения из таблицы с помощью PIL или других подоюных инструментов.

Comment: Недавно как раз наткнулся на доки бесплатной апишки QuickChart, там есть апишка для создания изображения таблицы. https://quickchart.io/documentation/apis/table-image-api/